# missing variable Google api key for android

Tags: ionic-framework

missing variable Google api key for android

> Failed to install 'uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator':
>   Error: Variable(s) missing: GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID at
>   Object.mergeVariables
>   (/opt/npm-packages/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman-151/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/plugman/variable-merge.js:58:15) at
>   /opt/npm-packages/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman-151/node_modules/pgb-cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:315:44
>   at _fulfilled
>   (/opt/npm-packages/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman-151/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54) at self.promiseDispatch.done
>   (/opt/npm-packages/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman-151/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30) at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
>   (/opt/npm-packages/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman-151/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13) at
>   /opt/npm-packages/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman-151/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
>   at flush
>   (/opt/npm-packages/lib/node_modules/pgb-plugman-151/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7) at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
>   Variable(s) missing: GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator#phonegap-build

Get maps api key from google and add to config.xml